# Easy way to gather all the common properties of a chart, to not write them all the time?

Tags: highcharts

I am drawing various charts on a page, and would like to avoid to have to declare in each chart, the properties that are common to every chart.

I tried an example found online, where the common part was in a {settings}, but when I try to load it, I had no luck.

I am using Highcharts. Any suggestion is more than welcome....with 16 charts on one page, I am just going crazy.

Comment: please provide the link to the example of where you looked for `settings` for reference and if possible please create a fiddle of your code so that we can understand what settings are needed in common

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge function. See the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nyQ2L/

```
var defaultOptions = {
    chart:{
        type:'line'
    },
    title: {
        text:'common title'
    }
};

var opt1 = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions,{
    series:[{
        data:[1,2,3]
    }]
});
```